# Redis tests don't exit after passing (using jest)

Tags: node.js, jestjs, node-redis

I implemented basic caching functionality for a project and ran into a problem during the testing.
I test using jest and redis-mock and all the tests pass.
The problem is when I import a file which imports the redis-file.
The test-file doesn't exit.

Example:

**index.test.js**

```
import redis from 'redis'
import redis_mock from 'redis-mock'
jest.spyOn(redis, 'createClient').mockImplementation(red_mock.createClient)
import fileUsingRedis from './index'

describe('index', () => {
  it('should pass', () => expect(true).toBeTruthy())
}
```

**index.js**

```
import {set} from './redis'
export default function ...
```

**redis.js**

```
import redis from 'redis'
const client = redis.createClient()

export function set(key, value) {...}
```

'1 passed'...'Ran all test suites matching ...'

But then it keeps waiting, I assume because the redis.createClient() is async or something or other. Seeing as it happens on the import I can't just resolve it.
Do I have to close the redis-instance connection after every test?

What is the solution/best-practice here?

Comment: `redis.createClient()` opens a file handle, so jest waits for that handle to close. To know what handles are still open, you can run jest with the `--detectOpenHandles` flag

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So yeah, closing the instance did it.

**index.test.js**

```
import redis from './redis'
...
afterAll(() => redis.closeInstance())
```

**redis.js**

```
export function closeInstance(callback) {
  client.quit(callback)
}
```